# How to break up a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, explode

Okay, so what I need to do is break up a large string that contains the same pattern at the beginning and end of each line.
I.e. I have a large string like so:

```
<p>echo "test";</p><p>$d = "something"; </p> //don't ask why - part of something bigger :)
```

I want to break it up, I assume I'll need to use explode, but the exploded strings should be an array like so:

```
['echo "test";' , '$d = "something";']
```

1. There will always be `<p>` tag at the start and `</p>` at the end of a line.
2. The "lines" should be stored in array as I need to loop over each single one of them
3. I want to get rid of the tags at the start and at the end of each line, i.e. if the line was to be `<p>echo '<p>test</p>'; </p>` I want to keep the inner p tags, i.e I wanna get: `echo '<p>test</p>';`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Traverse all the `TEXT_NODE`s, then push them in an array

Comment: You need to learn how regular expressions work.  And also FOR loops.  If you're positive that all your text will always be formed exactly the same way, it's just matter of taking the pieces and organizing them.

Comment: you can't nest `<p>` tags...

Comment: yes you can. I wouldn't say this otherwise. This is just a string, not processed html code.

Comment: I guess what @dandavis is saying is you shouldn't even have nested <p> tags in the first place since it's illegal (and maybe fix whatever is causing such a string to be generated in the first place). Of course, there is nothing stopping anyone from creating such a string in the first place.

Comment: the context of my comment was that RegExp is not good at processing recursive nested HTML and the DOM is no good at nested `<p>` tags, so JS doesn't have a simple solution...

Comment: I think I found an answer. Thank you all for time taken to help.

Comment: Could you tell us what you did?

Comment: check my answer below, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some experimental coding and came to this

```
code = code.replace(/(<(p)>)/ig,"<p> ");
```

what I am basically doing is replacing `<p>` tags with `<p>` followed by a space. Since I am exploding the string on space (' '), the echo is treated as a seperate word or token if you will, which was my desired output.

This way it will not really affect the inner p tags.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first `<p>` and the last `</p>` from your string and then `String.split('<p></p>')`.

Comment: removing first and last p tags programatically is what I intend to do.

Comment: Ok. What about the split I suggested?

Comment: does not give desired output :(

Answer (score -1):

You can just use `array.split("<p>")` and then go through each value in the array and replace `</p>` with empty space

```
var yourArrayData = yourData.split("<p>");
for(var i=0; i<yourArrayData.length; i++){
  yourArrayData[i] = yourArrayData[i].replace(/<\/p>/g, "");
}
```

Comment: I could, but wouldn't this split twice as there are two <p> tags? and also replacing </p> with empty space with replace both closing p tags, won't it? :)

Comment: Ah just saw your edit.. well in that case, how about you create invisible html element and then go through each and grabbing html of it?

Comment: And how would you do that?
Assume the code is entered by the user in the manner mentioned above, outer p tags are added automatically by the richtext editor. so, in order to process the code some how, and by this I mean process each word within the line (i.e. between outer p tags) I need to get rid of the outer p tags asthey are in the way.

Comment: Technically `p` tags inside `p` tags are not allowed.. or won't work properly.. better option is to have `p` inside `div`.. or `<br/>`

Comment: the p tags need to be removed on the outside as I don't want the whole thing to be nested. But I got this working :)